# How can I understand the Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-complexity, na.numerical-analysis

I want to do research on matrix multiplication algorithms. I glanced at the Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm paper, but I didn't understand anything. How can I complete the background to read this paper?

I am an undergraduate student with senior math maturity.

Comment: Same question [in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34173/114739). You are not alone! Answers for this question looks good to me; eg,see [\[1\]](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34178/114739), [\[2\]](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34195/114739)